# Aspect for annotated methods

Tags: spring, aspectj

I have a class with annotated methods:

```
@Service
class MessageService{
    @AutoWired
    MessageDao dao;
    public void setDao(MessageDao dao){
        this.dao=dao;
    }
    @Memoize
    public void addNode(Message m){

    }
    @Memoize
    public void updateNode(Message m){

    }
    @Memoize
    public List<Message> getMessagesByEntity(String key){

    }
}
```

I need to define an aspect to do some caching lookup/housekeeping activities @Around each of the above methods:

```
@Around("@annotation(com.spring.aspects.Memoize)")
    public Object handledMemoize(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
        .....
......
.....
        Object obj = pjp.proceed();
        if (args != null)
        {
            cache.put(Arrays.asList(args), obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Now the nature of the cache activity will be different for each of the above methods.
So I would need the aspect to behave differently depending on the actual method invoked.
How do I achieve this?
I would believe the best practice would be a separate aspect method for each of the underlying methods by combining the @Memoize and method name check somehow.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of utilizing an `Aspect` if the proxy code isn't even going to be the same for each method?  Why not just make this a part of the method?

Comment: Proxy code can be same for classes/types of methods.The idea was to figure out how to identify the type as part of the annotation;when there is another annotation in tow.

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple pointcuts for different types by convention, for example

```
execution(* *.(@Memoize get*)(..)),
execution(* *.(@Memoize add*)(..)), and
execution(* *.(@Memoize update*)(..))
```

You could also make your own annotations, like `@MemoizeRead, @MemoizeUpdate, @MemoizeAdd` to make the pointcuts more explicit.

Or, you could make a custom annotation with a parameter, like `@Cached(type=CacheType.READ)`, and then use a switch statement in your aspect.